# Correct way to access emojione in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, emojione

I have a PhoneGap App with AngularJs 1.5.5, OnsenUI 2 and EmojiOne.

I am trying to access the emojione variable inside of the angular controller:

```
ons.bootstrap.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$timeout','$http', '$sce', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $sce) {

    emojione.imageType = 'svg';
    emojione.sprites = true;
    emojione.imagePathSVGSprites = '../res/sprites/emojione.sprites.svg';
    ...
```

I have some function calls later on as well.

It is working as intended when i run it on my PC, but fails to resolve "emojione" (it is undefined) on android.
This is my first time working with angularjs and JavaScript so it may be something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading emojione library from a cdn?
Mobile has internet access?

Comment: Yes, It is the only library from a cdn, my App already connects to a Server somewhere in Europe so it should have internet access.

Comment: After removing the cdn reference, the library is now loaded, I guess cdn references are not a good Idea with phonegap. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with angularjs and standard javascript libraries, I like to make a module and factory simply for accessing the root variable, just like you are trying to do:

```
angular.module('emojioneModule', [])
.factory('emojione', function($window) {
    return $window.emojione;
});
```

This allows you to inject the reference, and allows you to mock up the emojione for unit tests, as you can inject a mock instead.

```
ons.bootstrap.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$timeout','$http', '$sce', 'emojione', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $sce, emojione) {

    emojione.imageType = 'svg';
    emojione.sprites = true;
    emojione.imagePathSVGSprites = '../res/sprites/emojione.sprites.svg';
    ...
```

However, you could just inject $window, and access it directly from there.

Comment: When I inject $window like I injected the other ones, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'imageType' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure the emojione script is being loaded before your controller is instantiated?

Comment: I wasn't, but after downloading the library and adding it directly it no longer crashes my application. I guess the cdn reference didn't work.